# How can I write Nuspec for MEF Plugin File

Tags: mef, nuget, nuspec

I want to write nuspec for MEF plugin.
I can copy xxx.dll to content directory, like below.

```
<files>
  <file src="Alhambra\bin\Release\Plugins\Alhambra.Plugin.SqlServer.dll" target="content\Plugins\Alhambra.Plugin.SqlServer.dll" />
  <file src="Alhambra\bin\Release\Alhambra.dll" target="lib\Alhambra.dll" />
</files>
```

but I can't set file property in user project to copy output directory.

Thanks for any suggestions or code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to add the plugin to the project as a separate file. For that you need an install script (see [NuGet docs for this](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal)).

My solution for this is the following script:

param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

```
Function add_file($file)
{
    $do_add = 1
    foreach($item in $project.DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects[0].ProjectItems)
    {
        if ($item -eq $file)
        { $do_add = 0 }
    }
    if ($do_add -eq 1)
    {
        $added = $project.DTE.ItemOperations.AddExistingItem($file)
        $added.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory").Value = 2
        $added.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = 0        
    }
}
add_file(<file1>)
add_file(<file2>)
```

Of course, when the user uninstalls the package, you need to clean up:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

Function remove_file($file)
{
    foreach($item in $project.DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects[0].ProjectItems)
    {
        if ($item.Name -eq $file)
        { 
          $item.Delete() 
        }
    }
}
remove_file(<file1>)
remove_file(<file2>)
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when using the ``install-package`` command from the nuget console. It'll try to add the files as Solution Items.